# Password-protected GRUB does not boot Ubuntu, but Windows works

Tags: boot, grub2, password

So, I was trying to password protect my Windows 8.1 partition following the under-mentioned tutorials:

1. http://www.howtogeek.com/102009/how-to-password-protect-ubuntus-boot-loader/
2. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords

And I successfully completed the process. Now, whenever I want to boot into my Windows partition from Grub it asks my username and password, I enter it and then it boots into Windows. All good till now.

But now the real problem arises is that whenever I want to boot into my Ubuntu partition, it asks for my username and password, so I enter it but it returns me back to the grub menu. Why???

And if you could then please instruct me with a workaround.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue. It was a mistake from my side as I entered

```
set supersusers="name"
```

instead of

```
set superusers="name"
```